# datalist: display matched choice from query in input text box

Tags: html, html-select, datalist

I have a form for editing existing data. The user chooses a record and then the form is pre-populated by a database query. Some of the form fields are presented as datalists (allowing pre-populated choices, but users can enter their own).

What I would like to do is to have these `datalist` elements appear with the current value for that key (from the db) showing in the text box atop the `datalist` - i.e., in the same manner that an `<option>` value can be matched to options in a `<select>` input and show that option in the `<select>` box when it is rendered.

I've added `selected` to the options list like this:

```html
<input type="search"
    name="Status"
    placeholder = "~ Status ~"
    id="Status" 
    list="statuslist">

<datalist id="statuslist">
    <select>
      <option value="launched">launched</option>
      <option value="pre-launch" selected>pre-launch</option>
      <option value="no company">no company</option>
    </select>
</datalist>
```

...but that doesn't seem to do the trick. The `datalist` input box always displays `~ Status ~` (the placeholder). If I remove the placeholder, it's just blank.

Does `datalist` support this kind of functionality? How do I make this happen?

Comment: Could you show us your relevant javascript/jquery code, please?

Comment: I'm using the datalist.js plugin.  So the only jquery is to load datalist.js in the <head> and then declare `$('input[list]').datalist();` at the end

Comment: Edit nevermind my selector comment, I saw now targeting the list is correct.

Comment: No luck with your solutions - still get the placeholder.  datalist.js just provides a cross-browser solution - it falls back to <select> if datalist not supported.

Comment: See my updated response below. I suspect thats what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datalist.js doesnt update with the selected value, you have to add this after the datalist initialization

```
//traverse each list
$('input[list]').each(function(){
    // variable for the jquery object of the selected option
    var datalist = $('#' + $(this).attr('list') + ' option:selected');
    // check if value, but also check if option has the attribute "selected"
    if(datalist.val() != 'undefined' && datalist.attr('selected')){
        // update selected to the pre-selected
        $(this).attr('value',datalist.text());
    }
});
```

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/hkoyarov/)

Edit: And added support for multiple lists as requested, and fixed error with the datalist.js fallback solution to avoid overwriting the placeholder if nothing selected.

Comment: That works!  Now just need to genericize this so that it's the default behavior for all datalist inputs. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yepp, `.each()` is nice for that, updated my answer. (Edit: btw the `focus()` isnt necessary, datalist.js seems to repopulate the list on blur/focus anyway when there is more than one list )

Comment: Brilliant.  Only one small quirk...when the particular datalist does not have a value returned from the db there isn't a "selected" option, but this code now displays the first option in the datalist instead of the placeholder.

Comment: That quirk doesn't seem to happen [in the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/e221yhz9/1/) with 3 boxes. Can you reproduce the error on that fiddle, update it, and link it to me?

Comment: I'm glad I helped, and if you feel I solved your original question, please remember to mark the answer as soon as you're able.

Comment: I can't get the jsfiddle to replicate the condition that is occurring.  Viewing the source code for my page, I see that a `value="launched"`is added to each of the <inputs> that don't have a `option:selected`. Similarly there is a `value="{db value}"` for each of the inputs where a datalist item has been selected.  Seems like this is exactly what the jquery code does: add the "value='{selected value}'" to the input. Right?  Definitely plan to accept this answer...

Comment: you could try to put the replacement line of the code into a IF sentence, something like `if($('#' + $(this).attr('list')).val() != "")`. It should check the list if it has a value selected. I'm sorry, without you being able to replicate the error in a fiddle, there isn't much I can do from here.

Comment: updated with another fiddle that might fix your problem, added variable for readability, and an if sentence that should avoid any errors caused by that line of code.

Comment: Mystery solved: datalist.js requires that <select> statements be inside the datalist for fall back purposes.  Replicated [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Transformer/qsagb896/1/).  Removing the <select> delivers the outcomes the jquery code above is expected to achieve.  Now I'll just have to choose: datalists? datalist.js? or back to old select inputs.

Comment: Thank you. Please explain the approach re: tagName and OPTION.

Comment: Sure, if `<option>` is not direct child of `<datalist>`, then it means there is a `<select>` in between, and from what I could gather that only happens when nothing is pre-selected. `.prop("tagName")` gives you the tag name of the element.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I had added `<select>` tags to option 3 to demonstrate the problem.  In production, `<select>' tags are always generated in every case for cross-browser compatibility. I've forked [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fLgje94/) to show that testing for the select tag won't, unfortunately, work.

Comment: Added a `datalist.attr('selected')` check, should fix you problem. Updated my answer..again :)